# Why is $f(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Why is this function uniformly continuous?

$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,

$f(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$.

I tried using the mean value theorem for several variables, but I am not able to complete it. Here is my attempt:

If we have two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, **a** and **b**. Then:

$|f(\textbf{a})-f(\textbf{b})|=|\triangledown f(\textbf{c}) \cdot(\textbf{b}-\textbf{a})|$, where **c** is a point on the line between **a** and **b**.

I get that the gradient is:

$-2*e^{-(c_1^2+c_2^2)}[c_1,c_2]$. I get that the fight HS then is:

$|\triangledown f(\textbf{c}) \cdot(\textbf{b}-\textbf{a})|=|-2e^{-(c_1^2+c_2^2)}[c_1,c_2]\cdot(\textbf{b}-\textbf{a})|\le |2[c_1,c_2]\cdot(\textbf{b}-\textbf{a})|$.

But how do I proceed? I need the c's to disappear and to have $|\textbf{b}-\textbf{a}|$,ont the right side. If I could get something with $(\textbf{b}-\textbf{a})\cdot(\textbf{b}-\textbf{a})$ that would be ok, but I don't see how to get it?

Comment: Find a bound on $$e^{-(c_1^2+c_2^2)}\cdot \lVert[c_1,c_2]\rVert.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I get that the upper bound for that is 1, then we use cauchy schwarz and we are done?

Comment: Yes. Of course there are other ways, but this gives you that the function is even Lipschitz-continuous and a Lipschitz constant.

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Fischer offered a fix for the proof in the comments: instead of the wasteful 
$$e^{-c_1^2-c_2^2}\sqrt{c_1^2+c_2^2}\le \sqrt{c_1^2+c_2^2}$$
is the estimate
$$e^{-c_1^2-c_2^2}\sqrt{c_1^2+c_2^2}\le \sup_{r>0} re^{-r}=e^{-1}$$
(since the supremum is attained at $r=1$).

For completeness, a more general result: if $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^n$ and tends to $0$ as $|x|\to\infty$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous. This can be proved by contradiction: suppose there is $\epsilon>0$ and two sequences $x_n,y_n$ such that $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$ and $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\ge \epsilon$. Then these sequences must be bounded (else $f$ would be too small), so we extract a convergent subsequence $x_n\to a$ and get a contradiction with the continuity of $f$ at $a$.